# Handle APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM using javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget

Tags: java, jax-rs, inputstream

I have a service which return APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM file using this code:

```
@GET
    public Response download(@BeanParam MovieUrl movieUrl) {

        log.info("Request {} is handled",movieUrl);

           final StreamingOutput fileStream = this.downloaderService.videoAsStream(movieUrl);

            log.info("ok");
            return Response.ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = movie.mp4")
                    .build();

    }
```

If I call this using browser I will get mp4 file as response.

But how to handle this file using `WebTarget` I tried:

```
webTarget.path("download")
                .queryParam("request",mapAsJson.apply(of("url",url)))
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .get(InputStream.class);
```

But it return HTTP 502 Bad Gateway